# SVN connector timeouts while connecting to repository

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I get the following when installing SVN from update site in eclipse

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=com.springsource.sts.ide, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/plugins/org.eclipse.team.svn.core_0.7.9.I20110321-1700.jar.
Timeout while reading input stream.
The following system properties can be used to adjust the readTimeout, retryAttempts, and closeTimeout
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=<default:1000>
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.retryAttempts=<default:30>
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=<default:1000>

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/plugins/org.eclipse.team.svn.help_0.7.9.I20110318-1700.jar.
Timeout while reading input stream.
The following system properties can be used to adjust the readTimeout, retryAttempts, and closeTimeout
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=<default:1000>
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.retryAttempts=<default:30>
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=<default:1000>

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/plugins/org.eclipse.team.svn.ui_0.7.9.I20110318-1700.jar.
Timeout while reading input stream.
The following system properties can be used to adjust the readTimeout, retryAttempts, and closeTimeout
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=<default:1000>
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.retryAttempts=<default:30>
    org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=<default:1000>
```

I've tried many times but get same error :(

Comment: check the URL http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/plugins/org.eclipse.team.svn.core_0.7.9.I20110321-1700.jar.... it's returning page not found error

Answer (score 0):

-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=3000

-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=3000

in your eclipse.ini  file